# To compare two input files in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two files

- Input 1 as `(1,2,3,4), (6,7,8,9), (4,5,3,8), (1,2,5,6)...`
- Input 2 as `(1,2)`

Now i want to compare both inputs and based on records in input 2 i.e (1,2) i want to remove all records from input 1 which includes (1,2) so in our case i need OUTPUT as

```
Output - (6,7,8,9), (4,5,3,8)...
```

Any idea how we can do in MapReduce or algorithm will help me..

Comment: What have you tried until now? You should show your own effort to the community, then people will be willing to help improve your approach.

Comment: There's a class called something like MultipleInputFormat. Did you try it?